# How to keep ratings in iOS 11 and the new store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

It is rumored that there will be an option to keep the star rating if I update my app. I can not find any information on that. Is it coming in fall?

Comment: Does someone see this feature today? 8th September 2017

Comment: Seen couple of apps ratings reset to 0, for example instagram, no update on itunesconnect. Have to wait till tomorrow to see if they introduce any changes in itunes connect while submitting app to app store.

Comment: Still cannot find it after the Apple Event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to keep ratings can be found in *iTunes Connect*, select the new version to be released, then scroll at the bottom and see *Reset iOS Summary Rating*.

[image]

This option has became live with the release of iOS 11 on September 19, 2017.

Comment: I am doing an update and I don't see that option. I haven't any additional sections below  "Phased Release for Automatic Updates".

Comment: Admin or App Manager role is needed to see Reset iOS Summary Rating. I didn't see it because I had Technical role.

Answer (score 0):

Techcrunch says its coming in September.

https://techcrunch.com/2017/06/07/ios-app-developers-will-be-able-to-keep-app-store-ratings-when-releasing-an-update/

Comment: You should research *before* you post a question.

Comment: Thats is correct and I did. But I did not come across that post. I am leaving it up for reference.